# Which chart from highcharts's collection is being used on stackexchange's sites?

Tags: support

If I am not wrong then stackexchange's engine is using [highcharts](http://highcharts.com) for this, but I was wondering which specific chart(s) from there huge collection is being used here?

As you can see there are two charts here: [image] and they interact with each other, but I was not able to find a similar graph in Highchart's collection.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you mean the reputation chart on user pages?

Comment: @Anko Yes, exactly.

Comment: Why do you conclude it's using Highcharts? [D3](http://d3js.org/) could produce the same effect, as could some JQuery plugin.

Comment: @Anko From the source code: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/third-party/highcharts.js?v=47c74ab4650f

Comment: I find a few hits in the `user.en.js` file if search for "Highcharts" in the page source. [The first one](http://i.imgur.com/NCm4nPK.png) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Basic column" is being used.

There are two instances of highcharts which work together to combine into what visually looks like a single chart.

The bottom chart is the "master" graph and spans the time frame of every data point available. The top chart is the "detail" graph and spans the selected time frame from the master graph.

Both of these charts are typed as `"defaultSeriesType": "column"`, and the **[demo at Highcharts.com](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic)** provides a very similar looking graph to work with as a starter.

[image]

Comment: how both chart interact to each other ? I mean I understand detail chart pick time from master chart but is their any event available to connect them ?

Comment: @404ErrOR - Not built in, that is all custom script, perhaps by balpha or another one of the SE team.